# Custom validation contact form7

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I need validation of the form - if someone enters a phone number / email then no email / phone number is no longer required. I tried

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".wpcf7-email").on('change', function postinput(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            if(id) {
                   document.getElementById('phone').setAttribute("aria-required", "false");
                   $( "#phone" ).removeClass( "wpcf7-validates-as-required" )
           } else {
                   document.getElementById('phone').setAttribute("aria-required", "true");
           }
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

And tried PHP

```
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'xyz_validation', 20, 2 );

    function xyz_validation( $result, $tag ) {

        $email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
        $phone = isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ? trim( $_POST['phone'] ) : '';

        if ( !empty($email) && !empty($subject) ) {
          $result->invalidate( $tag, "Really?" );
        }
```

My contact form (jquery - in PHP form is not required (no sign '*')

```
[email* email id:email]
[number* phone id:phone]
```

Comment: You haven't outlined what the actual issue is.

Comment: My code (jquery and php) doesn't work correctly. I need only one information - phone or email, for example when somebody types in email, then he doesn't have to type phone number. Contact form7 version 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this, without using the javascript, is to use the [Smart Grid-layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), it has been designed to compensate for the many shortcomings of CF7 plugin.  It introduces a custom validation hook
 which allows submissions to be validated in the light of the entire submitted dataset,

```
add_filter( 'cf7sg_validate_submission','validate_field_submission',10,3);
function validate_field_submission($validation_errors, $submission, $cf7_key){
  if('my-contact-form'==$cf7_key ){ //check this is the right form.
    //$validation_errors is an array of field-names=>error messages.
    //these include the simple validation exposed in the CF7 plugin for required fields/special field formats.
    if(!empty($submission['phone']) && wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) == $validation_errors['email']){
      //reset the error message.
      $validation_errors['email'] = '';
    }
    if(!empty($submission['email']) && wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) == $validation_errors['phone']){
      //reset the error message.
      $validation_errors['phone'] = '';
    }
  return $validation_errors;
  }    
}
```